# How do I add more buttons to Multiple Show/Hide DIV

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a problem connecting DIV's "q4", "q5", "q6", and "q7" to their rightful places. I want q4 to show when tablet is clicked, q5 to show when Macbook is clicked, q6 to show when Mac is clicked, and q7 to show when iPod is clicked. Could some please explain to me how this is done? I look at the javascript below and I kind of see a pattern but how do I add more buttons?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(1);"><button>iPhone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(2);"><button>Cell Phone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)"><button>iPad</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)"><button>iPod</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(4);"><button>Tablet</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(5);"><button>Macbook</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(6)"><button>Mac</button></a>
</td>
</table>
<div id="q1" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 5</button>
<button>iPhone 4S</button>
<button>iPhone 4</button>
<button>iPhone 3GS</button>
</div>
<div id="q2" style="display: none;">
<button>HTC</button>
<button>Nokia</button>
<button>Motorola</button>
<button>Blackberry</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
<button>LG</button>
</div>
<div id="q3" style="display: none;">
<button>iPad Mini</button>
<button>iPad 4th Generation</button>
<button>iPad 3rd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 2nd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 1st Generation</button>
</div>
<div id="q4" style="display: none;">
<button>Apple</button>
<button>Amazon</button>
<button>Asus</button>
<button>Google</button>
<button>Microsoft</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
</div>
<div id="q5" style="display: none;">
<button>Macbook</button>
<button>Macbook Air</button>
<button>Macbook Pro</button>
</div>
<div id="q6" style="display: none;">
<button>iMac</button>
<button>Mac Mini</button>
<button>Mac Pro</button>
</div>
<div id="q7" style="display: none;">
<button>Touch</button>
<button>Nano</button>
<button>Classic</button>
</div>
<div id="qq1" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T</button>
<button>Sprint</button>
<button>Verizon</button>
<button>T-Mobile</button>
<button>Unlocked</button>
<button>Other</button>
</div>
<div id="qqq1" style="display: none;">
<button>test1</button>
<button>test2</button>
<button>test3</button>
</div>
<script>
function showHide(obj) {
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subSubShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Good thing that you have added the whole HTML code

Comment: @NishaS people usually want that. Do you know how the code works?

Comment: @user2680614 Okay so I tried to run the code, it works, what exactly do you want help with?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta q4, q5, q6, q7 don't show up when I click on their rightful buttons. When I click "Tablet" q4 is suppose to show up and so on but they don't. How do I put them inside the javascript below so that they do?

Comment: Look here: http://jsbin.com/UpiMaKu/1/edit?html,js,output I've edited your code to reflect how it works. I see that Clicking on tablet does open up the submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the culprit, you were trying to call a function to show the 5th element or 6th element, but inside the function you checked only till 4 objects. Made a small correction and things should work.

Working code below :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<table>
<td>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(1);"><button>iPhone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(2);"><button>Cell Phone</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)"><button>iPad</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)"><button>iPod</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(4);"><button>Tablet</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(5);"><button>Macbook</button></a>
<a href="#" onclick="showHide(6)"><button>Mac</button></a>
</td>
</table>
<div id="q1" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="subShowHide('1');">iPhone 5</button>
<button>iPhone 4S</button>
<button>iPhone 4</button>
<button>iPhone 3GS</button>
</div>
<div id="q2" style="display: none;">
<button>HTC</button>
<button>Nokia</button>
<button>Motorola</button>
<button>Blackberry</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
<button>LG</button>
</div>
<div id="q3" style="display: none;">
<button>iPad Mini</button>
<button>iPad 4th Generation</button>
<button>iPad 3rd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 2nd Generation</button>
<button>iPad 1st Generation</button>
</div>
<div id="q4" style="display: none;">
<button>Apple</button>
<button>Amazon</button>
<button>Asus</button>
<button>Google</button>
<button>Microsoft</button>
<button>Samsung</button>
</div>
<div id="q5" style="display: none;">
<button>Macbook</button>
<button>Macbook Air</button>
<button>Macbook Pro</button>
</div>
<div id="q6" style="display: none;">
<button>iMac</button>
<button>Mac Mini</button>
<button>Mac Pro</button>
</div>
<div id="q7" style="display: none;">
<button>Touch</button>
<button>Nano</button>
<button>Classic</button>
</div>
<div id="qq1" style="display: none;">
<button onclick="subSubShowHide('1');">AT&T</button>
<button>Sprint</button>
<button>Verizon</button>
<button>T-Mobile</button>
<button>Unlocked</button>
<button>Other</button>
</div>
<div id="qqq1" style="display: none;">
<button>test1</button>
<button>test2</button>
<button>test3</button>
</div>
<script>
function showHide(obj) {
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=6;i++){  //CHANGED THIS LINE
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('q'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
}
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
function subSubShowHide(obj){
for(i=1;i<=1;i++){
    if (i == obj) {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('qqq'+i).style.display = 'none';
    }
}
return false;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Although this code would work as expected by you, remember to use a better naming convention  like I've demonstrated in my example [HERE.](http://jsbin.com/UpiMaKu/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: There's one problem with the code; when I click on ipod it shows the contents for the ipad. How do I fix that?

Comment: You need to change `<a href="#" onclick="showHide(3)"><button>iPod</button></a>` to `<a href="#" onclick="showHide(7)"><button>iPod</button></a>` and change the loop `for(i=1;i<=6;i++){ ` to `for(i=1;i<=7;i++){ `

Comment: Oh hey I got your message from yesterday about helping me out. I could really use your help. You can email me ryanwilliams1000@gmail.com or invite me to a chat.

Comment: I have another code that I could show you also that is very handy.

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery `show`/`hide` methods:

```
<script>
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
     $(".groupClass").show("fast");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I already have that incorporated in the code. Could you maybe provide me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

**I want q4 to show when tablet is clicked**

```
$('#tablet').click(function(){
$('#q4').show();
});
```

here `tablet` and `q4` are `IDs` of the elements(button or div) respectively.

Same goes for the q5,q6 and so on you just need to change the `IDs`.
I think some of my seniors have answered it before but I think I have cleared my self in a more clear ways that the questioner wants :)

Comment: I did what you said but I'm still getting an error. Maybe you could provide me with a jfiddle?

Comment: you can use in your function `showHide` like this :
If(obj == 4) { then my code }